# I am trying to render only those items that belong to another controller in React

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am working on a travel planning web app project in Rails and Ract.
In my Ruby on Rails backend I have a model Place that belongs to my model Trip. in React.js on the frontend I am trying to render just those places that belong to a certain trip in a Modal. At present, I am rendering all the places in my database (because on my backend the index method in calling Place.all) so when I open my Modal for a certain trip, it displays all of the places rather than just the places that belong to that trip.

I need a way on either the back or front end to render only those places that belong to the trip that I am opening in the Modal

Currently my code looks like this:

Rails backend:
`def index  @places = Place.all render json: @places.as_json end`

React frontend
Home.jsx

```
//Places actions
  const [places, setPlaces] = useState([]);

  const handleIndexPlaces = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/places.json").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setPlaces(response.data);
    });
  };
  useEffect(handleIndexPlaces, []);
```

//returning

```
 <Modal show={isTripShowVisable} onClose={handleHideTrip}>
   <TripsShow places={places} trips={trips} />
 </Modal>
```

//tripsShow

```
export function TripsShow(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Places to visit on this trip:</h2>
      <div>
        {props.places.map((place) => {
          return (
            <div key={place.id}>
              <h3>{place.name}</h3>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have tried changing the backend to Place.where(trip_id: current_trip.id) but I know that I don't currently have a current_trip so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the trip ID as a parameter in the axios GET request to the backend, and then retrieve only the places that belong to the trip with the same ID in the controller.

### Backend:

```
def index
trip_id = params[:trip_id]
@places = Place.where(trip_id: trip_id)
render json: @places.as_json
end
```

### Frontend:

```
const handleIndexPlaces = (trip_id) => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/places.json? 
    trip_id=${trip_id}`).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setPlaces(response.data);
  });
};
```

The `TripsShow` takes more props now, it needs the selected trip, and a function to resolve the places for it :

```
<Modal show={isTripShowVisable} onClose={handleHideTrip}>
  <TripsShow places={places} trips={trips} handleIndexPlaces={handleIndexPlaces} trip={selectedTrip} />
</Modal>



export function TripsShow(props) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    props.handleIndexPlaces(props.trip.id);
  }, []);

return (
  <>
    <h2>Places to visit on this trip:</h2>
    <div>
      {props.places.map((place) => {
        return (
          <div key={place.id}>
            <h3>{place.name}</h3>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first address the backend concerns.

You need to setup assocations between the models and create a [nested route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) which returns the places for a specific trip.

`Place.where(trip_id: current_trip.id)` implies that the assocation is one-to-many:

```
class Place
  belongs_to :trip
end

class Trip
  has_many :places
end
```

`Place.where(trip_id: current_trip.id)` is smelly as it leaks the implementation details of your models. The controller should just know that `Trip` has a `places` method and not the nitty gritty details.

But I wonder if you don't actually want a [many-to-many assocation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) as it seems strange that that different trips can't visit the same place.

```
class Place
  has_many :trip_places
  has_many :trips, through: :trip_places
end

class Trip
  has_many :trip_places
  has_many :places, through: :trip_places
end

# for lack of a better name
# rails g model TripPlace trip:belongs_to place:belongs_to
class TripPlace
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :place
end
```

Then you want to setup the nested route:

```
resources :trips do
  resources :places, shallow: true
end
```

This will define the route `/trips/:trip_id/places` which RESTfully defines that there is a relationship between the two resources.

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /trips/1/places
  # GET /trips/1/places.json
  def index
    @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id]) # this can be DRYed into a callback
    @places = @trip.places
    render json: @places # you don't need to explicitly call `.as_json`
  end
end
```

While you could acheive the same result with a query string parameter - `places?trip_id=1` that's an implicit instead of explicit relation and not the Rails Way of handling nested resources. As an added bonus this will also reurn a `404 - Not Found` if the trip id is not valid instead of just an empty collection.

You should then adjust your frontend code so that it sends a request to the correct url:

```
const handleIndexPlaces = (trip_id) => {
  // don't hardcode `http://localhost:3000` into your JS.
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/trips/${trip_id}/places`).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    setPlaces(response.data);
  });
};
```